# Already logged in on Facebook, why the need to re-authenticate when using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise

I am using Devise and omniauth-facebook gem. I have successfully configured it. However, I wonder why I need to re-authenticate when I click the sign-in link in my app, when I am already logged in on Facebook on another tab in my browser? Shouldn't it be some magic here? Or is that expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It's expected. That's facebook's way of making sure you a user is actually trying to give someone access to their information.

Comment: Ok, but spotify and such apps automagically logs you in? They do something different then I guess?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out using this method:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign in', volunteer_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

It works as expected. When a user is logged in to Facebook he/she does not have to reenter authentication information. When signing out of Facebook the user has to reauthenticate.

Awesome.

Comment: I just implemented this in an app a few days ago. As I recall, a user has to provide their password to (facebook) the first time to authorize transmission of data and to create the user. Subsequent times they don't though because they've already done so and it's just creating a session instead of a new user. Testing it in my own app, that's exactly how it went down. This comes from doing it and my recollection of the documentation of either OA or FB's API. Digging into source on either side may prove that incorrect.